# How to access a textbox in my main window from a different class?

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is a very simple problem but I'm having a bit of an issue here. I will paste the whole code at the end for the WPC form + another class, sorry it is long but just search for the word ISSUE and you'll get to the line with the problem straightaway

**What I want to achieve**

--My main WPF c# window is called MainWindow and has a textbox txtLog

--One of my class called clientHandler needs to change the value in txtLog

--At the moment i pass a reference to MainWindow class to the MainWindowHandle method from my MainWindow window.

**The long code - Please search for the word ISSUE for the problem line in my ClientHandler class**

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class ServerWindow : Window
{


        public static int NoOfRunningClients;
        public static ClientHandler[] RunningClientsPool = new ClientHandler[50];
        public static ClientHandler test;
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public ServerWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }


        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
            NoOfRunningClients = 0;
            //RunningClientsPool[NoOfRunningClients];

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                RunningClientsPool[NoOfRunningClients] = new ClientHandler();
                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(RunningClientsPool[NoOfRunningClients].AcceptCallback),
                    listener);
                RunningClientsPool[NoOfRunningClients].MainWindowHandle = this;

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
                NoOfRunningClients++;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();


    }

        }






    }
```

---

**ClientHandler**

```
public class ClientHandler
{
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public ClientHandler(Socket newSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = newSocket;
    }
    public ClientHandler()
    {

    }
    public String MyName { get; set; }
    public Window MainWindowHandle { get; set; }
    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.

                // ISSUE: I want to use something like this 
                //but have the static reference problem
                //MainWindowHandle.txtLog.Text = "It WORKS!!!!!"; 


                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

Thank you very much for your time, just to repeat, I want to be able to access txtLog in the MainWindow and other GUI elements without getting constant static member / nonstatic member issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially with WPF where [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) is supported and encouraged, you should not be passing references to forms around.  This is exactly the kind of problem that the MVVM architecture addresses.

Look into [binding both UI elements to the same model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx), so that a change in either UI element or in the model is reflected in all three places at once.

Comment: Also, please remove all that TCP-related stuff from the `Window`'s code behind. It hurts my eyes just trying to read that.

Comment: sorry i did myreading up on it, but for the small project i am doing it seems like an overkill to use MVVM. I have doen plenty of coding already, I'll have to redesign it all together and im the only developer , so i need a solution to just fix it as it is

Comment: It is never overkill to use MVVM.  It is appropriate even for tiny projects.  The learning curve may be steep if you have not done it before, but even the smallest projects benefit from it... and it is easy to do once you are experienced in applying it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would work or not but I would try to make a property in the class 'ClientHandler' and set it potentially to bubble to other views and such.  Something like

```
public string response { get; set; }

...
// ISSUE: I want to use something like this 
//but have the static reference problem
//MainWi

response = "It WORKS!!!!!"; // set the response PROPERTY to be set
```

Then as long as class is public it can be viewed and set on other objects when you instantiatie it.

```
ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler();
... (perform operations on class that invokes method)
TextBox.Text = ch.response  // as long as your event or method is performed that updates the property it will be set.
```

Honestly though I agree with Eric J.  MVVM is much much much better at this kind of thing.  It isolates events, methods, and properties and keeps them seperate in a ViewModel and then you bind to that what you need.  This is an advantage as you can nest properties and choose how they bind.  It is more difficult to initially set up but oh so much better in the long run to work with when having multiple things talk to each other.

Comment: thx.yes the MVVM sounds better definitely, i'm checking that now.

Comment: In addition to what Eric already stated this article is a GREAT START.  It is a complete solution with a lot of the tricks of how it works.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: ok like i said above, i have done most of the coding already, it isnt a big project and it looks like i'll have to redo the whole thing to fit it to mvvm, i'd just like to fix it as it is somehow and get it going rather than doing the whole coding again

Comment: My code above may work, give it a shot.  It is not tested though as your code example was quite larger than I am willing to recreate piece by piece.